# Loss carry forward with dplyr and mutate

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

I am working on a tax model in R and I need to do a loss carry-forward, and I'm struggling for how to do it without another (!) loop in my code.  Perhaps you have a suggestion?

Reproducible example below:

```
taxable_income<-c(-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,20,20,20,20,20) #define taxable income amounts
data_test<-data.frame(taxable_income) #put into data frame
data_test$carry_fwd<-0 #initialize carry forward and tax payable columns
data_test$tax_payable<-0
tax_rate<-0.27 #tax rate of 27%
#what I would like to be able to do is conditionally carry-forward a loss so that I end up with the following:
data_test$carry_fwd[1]<-ifelse(data_test$taxable_income[1]<0,data_test$taxable_income[1],0)  #first year, carry-forward balance only depends on in-year taxable income
data_test$tax_payable[1]<-max(data_test$taxable_income[1],0)*tax_rate  #first year, taxable only depends on in-year taxable income
for(i in seq(2,NROW(data_test))) {
  #carry forward any further losses and/or any carried forward losses not yet offset by income
  data_test$carry_fwd[i]<-ifelse(data_test$taxable_income[i]+data_test$carry_fwd[i-1]<0,data_test$taxable_income[i]+data_test$carry_fwd[i-1],0)
  #pay taxes if the income net carried forward losses is positive
  data_test$tax_payable[i]<-max(data_test$taxable_income[i]+data_test$carry_fwd[i-1],0)*tax_rate
  }
```

The loop works fine, but since this is a block of code that will be replicated many times, I'd like to find a way to work this through a faster (dplyr?) script.  The rest of the model code is done using tidyverse - is this perhaps a place to apply purr?

Comment: Looks the `carry_fwd` could be obtained by `ifelse(cumsum(taxable_income) < 0, cumsum(taxable_income), 0)` using baseR, but no loop.

Comment: Yes, @AntoniosK, to a point - the issue (I think) comes in when I get to the later rows when I can only use part of the carried-forward losses to offset in-year taxable income.

Comment: AFAIK, It's not possible to do anything else than a for loop when the calculation at the ith row is dependent on the i-1th row. `purrr::map` is basically the tidyverse version of `lapply()`.

Comment: @Phil why not using a `lag` value in that case?

Comment: @AndrewLeach you might be able to `group_by` year (from `dplyr`) if you want to calculate some metrics that must take into account ONLY within-year info.

Comment: @AntoniosK Because `lag()` vectorises, which is undesirable in this case. `data_test$carry_fwd <- ifelse(data_test$taxable_income + lag(data_test$carry_fwd) < 0, data_test$taxable_income + lag(data_test$carry_fwd), 0)` will get you a different set of results.

Comment: I agree with that, but the problem in this case is not the vectorisation. It's the fact the calculation in row `i` depends not only on row `i-1`, but in previous rows as well. But, for what you mentioned before, if the only thing you need to know in row `i` is the previous row, then I think `lag` will work. PS: I tend to use `lag` from `dplyr` :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dplyr solution :)

```
library(tidyverse)

tax_rate <- 0.27
data_test <- tibble(taxable_income = c(-10,-10,-10,-10,-10,20,20,20,20,20))

data_test %>% 
  mutate(cum_sum     = cumsum(taxable_income),
         carry_fwd   = if_else(cum_sum <= 0, cum_sum, 0),
         tax_payable = case_when(cum_sum  > taxable_income & cum_sum > 0     ~ taxable_income * tax_rate,
                                 cum_sum <= taxable_income & cum_sum > 0     ~ cum_sum * tax_rate,
                                 T ~ 0)) %>% 
  select(-cum_sum)
```

**Results**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   taxable_income carry_fwd tax_payable
            <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1            -10       -10         0  
 2            -10       -20         0  
 3            -10       -30         0  
 4            -10       -40         0  
 5            -10       -50         0  
 6             20       -30         0  
 7             20       -10         0  
 8             20         0         2.7
 9             20         0         5.4
10             20         0         5.4
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil! Even though I hate support columns it made sense this time ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Phil! I want to test this and make sure I understand it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: This was @Charlicito's answer

Comment: @Charlicito your approach replicates the results, but I did a bit of testing and it runs into another issue if you have a period of profits, then more losses to carry forward, since the cumsum() will reflect the historic profits, whereas the tax rules aren't path dependent - you don't get a different treatment when you have profits before losses vs just losses.  If you run your solution with `tibble(taxable_income = c(-10,-10,-10,-10,3000,-10,-10,-10,20,20))`, you'll see what I mean.  I think I might be stuck with the loop as @antoniosK points out.

Comment: @AndrewLeach i see your point. Maybe it is easier with a loop after all :)